# How do you debug 3D raycasts?

Tags: c#, godot

In Godot, if a 3D raycast isn't hitting where you'd expect it to hit, how do you debug it? I'm looking for some way to draw the ray (or a line that follows the ray), problem is, I can't find anything in the docs, so your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Just in case we're talking about code: I'm using Godot with C#, not GD script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Sadly there is no easy way to accomplish a "Line3D" in Godot (There are some free assets and third party solutions for that).*

However, being for debug purposes, all you have to do is enable "Visible Collision Shapes" on the "Debug" menu.

---

A common use of `RayCast` is to do them from the `Camera`. In which case they probably look like a point. And if you are also updating them every frame, they would follow the camera continuing to look like a point.

In that case, I suggest to duplicate or stop updating the `RayCast` you want to inspect on a key press. Said another way: Check if the user pressed a key, and when they do, either duplicate or stop updating the `RayCast`. *Then you can move around and see the `RayCast` from an angle where it does not look like a point.*